# Can every automorphism of a finite abelian group $A$ of exponent $e$ be lifted to an automorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}/e)^{\text{rk}(A)}$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group of exponent $e$ and rank $r$ (ie $r$ is the minimum cardinality of a generating set).

Pick a surjection $\pi : (\mathbb{Z}/e)^r\rightarrow A$.

Is every automorphism of $A$ liftable to an automorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}/e)^r$ via $\pi$?

Comment: I'd suggest your remark be removed from your post, as it doesn't add anything.  Instead, you might want to add your own thoughts to the question, to improve it.  Are you stuck?  What has you stuck?  Can you share with us what keeps you from being able to answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, and is a consequence of Gaschutz' lemma (see e.g. [Proposition 1.5 here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/LubPak.pdf)). Ie, given any generating tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_r)$ of $A$ and automorphism $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(A)$, one can lift $(a_1,\ldots,a_r)$ and $(\sigma(a_1),\ldots,\sigma(a_r))$ to generating tuples of $(\mathbb{Z}/e)^r$. Since these generate $(\mathbb{Z}/e)^r$, the first is mapped to the second by a unique automorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}/e)^r$ (this uses the freeness of $(\mathbb{Z}/e)^r$), which is precisely a lifting of $\sigma$.